# Python random.randint stops randomizing after a few loops

Tags: python

I'm running a python script that will display messages on a board.  One of the subroutines that I've created is supposed to grab a random line from a small text file, and display that line.  It mostly works, except after looping a few times, it gets stuck on the same number, and just displays the same thing over and over.

I am running this in Python 2.7, on a Raspberry Pi in Raspbian.  I am using this github as the base for the project, and added lines of my own to it: 
        https://github.com/CalebKussmaul/Stranger-Things-Integrated
This is part of a halloween display that will be Stranger Things-themed, so the preloaded messages have a reference to the show.  I noticed this issue the other day, and have been pouring over the internet to try and figure out what the problem could be.  I've tried doing different methods of selecting a randomized number, including some in some similar (but different) threads on this site.  All of them produce exactly the same issue.

Below is the subroutine I created:

```
def preloaded_messages():
    print "Preloaded Messages thread is loaded."
    global displaying
    while True:
        if not displaying:
            with open('preloaded_messages.txt') as f:
                lines = len(f.readlines())
                rgn = random.randint(1,lines)
                msg = linecache.getline('preloaded_messages.txt', rgn)
                print "rng: ", rgn
                print "total lines: ", lines
                print "line: ", msg
            print "displaying from preloaded_messages.txt: ", msg
            display(msg)
        time.sleep(10)
```

And here's my preloaded_messages.txt file:

```
help me
im trapped in the upside down
leggo my eggo
friends dont lie
run /!
hopper is alive
rip barb
demogorgon is coming /!
mouthbreather
```

When I run it, my output is like this:

```
rng:  6
total lines:  9
line:  hopper is alive

rng:  2
total lines:  9
line:  im trapped in the upside down

rng:  9
total lines:  9
line:  mouthbreather

...

rng:  9
total lines:  9
line:  mouthbreather
```

the first few times are always random (and the number of times it successfully randomizes varies), but when it gets on 9, it just stays there for as long as I let it run.  I am at a loss as to why it works the first few times, but not once it gets to 9.

EDIT: Interestingly, as I've been writing this, I also tried adding a blank line at the end, and while it looked like it'd be stuck again, as it did that one three times in a row, then it finally moved to others.  I'm not sure how that changes things. And ideally, I'd rather not have the blank line in there, as it eats up time displaying nothing.  So it'd be nice to fix the issue.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: And you're running this from the command line and not from an IDE of some sort?

Comment: yes, it's being run from the command line on the pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reseeding the random generator. See line 49 of stranger.py in the https://github.com/CalebKussmaul/Stranger-Things-Integrated: `random.seed(i)`.

The `color_of` function should be written as:

```
def color_of(i):
    """
    This function generates a color based on the index of an LED. This will always return the same color for a given
    index. This allows the lights to function more like normal christmas lights where the color of one bulb wont change.

    :param i: index of LED to get color of
    :return: a pseudorandom color based on the index of the light
    """
    _random = random.Random(i)
    rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(_random.random(), 1, 1)
    return int(rgb[0] * 255), int(rgb[1] * 255), int(rgb[2] * 255)
```

To create its own `Random` instance with the given seed rather than reseeding the `Random` instance that is a singleton in the `random` module.

Comment: Holy smokes, it worked!  Thank you!  I had no idea that the random generator would be tied together like that to other uses of it in the code.  I am finding that it repeats some more than others, but it is far and away better than it was, and isn't getting stuck on the same one for more than twice in a row..

Comment: The generator is uniform. It only appear to generate some more than others because you are looking at a small sample. If you do a few thousand samples and graph them on a histogram the divergence from uniform will decrease with increasing numbers of samples. The output of MT isn't complete decorrelated as it is sampling points from the surface of a 24-sphere. But at least it isn't as bad as RANDU.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me. Note that I'm seeding the RNG.

```
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime

def preloaded_messages():
  print("Preloaded Messages thread is loaded.")
  displaying = False
  while True:
    if not displaying:
      with open('preloaded_messages.txt') as f:
        random.seed(datetime.utcnow())
        text = f.read().splitlines()
        msg = random.choice(text)
        print("line: ", msg)
      # print("displaying from preloaded_messages.txt: ", msg)
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  preloaded_messages()
```

Comment: I adjusted my subroutine to match yours, and removed the blank last line, it got stuck on mouthbreather again.  as soon as I added the blank line, it did the blank line 3 times in a row, and started doing others again.  I am wondering if it has something to do with the timing in how long it takes to display the mouthbreather vs the blank line.  But I'm just reaching at this point.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb that's just so you can run the snippet in repl.it in isolation...

Comment: @MarkCampbell Strange, it works fine for me... Here's a working example: https://repl.it/@n1ckdm/CooperativeUniqueOop

Comment: @NickMartin The main differences that I'm seeing between this, and what I have to make it work, is the following: 1) it's not in a function 2) the timer is different (1 vs 10), 3) it's not calling the display function.  I don't think that there's anything in the display function that's altering anything, but rather, I'm pointing it out that the larger spacing in time seems to be a factor.

Comment: What is the display function? @MarkCampbell

Comment: Also, I'm finding it to not be very random at all--I'm finding this pattern to be repeating:
```
demogorgon is coming /!
friends dont lie
im trapped in the upside down
<blank>
mouthbreather
<blank>
<blank>
<blank>
```
which turns out to be 8, 4, 2, 10, 9, 10, 10, 10.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb, the pi is connected to a string of neopixel style lights, and the display function takes the line of text, and converts each letter to a corresponding light, and lights them one letter at a time.  As a result, when you pass a 10 character phrase to the display function, it will take about 10 secs to run the display before returning.

Comment: @MarkCampbell I've used a function call and increased the sleep time to 10 seconds. I still find that it works fine. I've added `random.seed()` call so and also used `splitlines()` to remove the newlines - perhaps try that on the pi?

Comment: Found the issue.  Dan D's comment below.  I didn't realize that separate uses of random could be tied together like that, and it seems that that was the culprit.